# Variable php no vacía no imprime valores

Tags: php, mysqli, scrapy

estoy haciendo scrap de una web y almacenándolos en una base de datos mysqli.
Antes de guardarla las imprimo en pantalla para observar que se están capturando correctamente y todo marcha perfecto, todas mis variables muestran los datos capturados de scrap perfectamente.
El problema es que al guardarlo en la DB, tengo 2 variables que no se guardan. Los demás datos se guardan bien, y el mysql no genera errores. Lo raro es que esas 2 variables (EquipoGanador y EquipoPerdedor) sí se imprimen correctamente al momento de ser capturadas. Haciendo pruebas, observo que esas variables no están vacías, pero no se almacenan en la DB sus valores. Porqué no se almacenan sus valores en la DB si ellas se imprimen correctamente como string?

```html
//Scrap
    $nombre_match = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($nombre_match_web));
    $status_match = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($estatus_match_web));
    $EquipoGanador = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($team_won_web));
    $EquipoPerdedor = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($team_lost_web));
    $EquipoGanador_Puntos = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($points_team_won_web));
    $EquipoPerdedor_Puntos = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($points_team_lost_web));
    $link_match = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($link_match_web));
```

Aquí imprimo para verificar si se capturan correctamente los datos:

```html
//Imprimo en pantalla
echo "Nombre del match: " . $nombre_match . "<br>";
echo "Estatus del match: " . $status_match . "<br>";
echo "Equipo ganador: " . $EquipoGanador . "<br>";
echo "Equipo perdedor: " . $EquipoPerdedor . "<br>";
echo "Puntos equipo ganador: " . $EquipoGanador_Puntos . "<br>";
echo "Puntos equipo perdedor: " . $EquipoPerdedor_Puntos . "<br>";
echo "Enlace del match: " . $url . "<br>";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esa es la imagen que muestra que tanto EquipoGanador como EquipoPerdedor, se capturan y se muestran correctamente.

La sentencia mysqli es:

```html
//ESCRIBIMOS LOS DATOS EN TABLA MATCH HISTORY DE LA BASE DE DATOS
include('conexion.php');
$sql = "INSERT INTO live_match_history (NombreMatch, EstatusMatch, EquipoGanador, EquipoPerdedor, EquipoGanador_Puntos, EquipoPerdedor_Puntos, EnlaceMatch) VALUES ('$nombre_match','$status_match', '$EquipoGanador','$EquipoPerdedor','$EquipoGanador_Puntos', '$EquipoPerdedor_Puntos', '$url')";

if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 ?><script>
  alert("Guardado en Tabla Live History!");
 </script><?php
}else{
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conexion->error;
};
```

Aquí la imagen de la tabla donde se muestran los campos vacíos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al final hice la prueba siguiente, sin poder guardar el valor de la variable en la tabla.

```html
if ($EquipoGanador==''){
 $EquipoGanador="Variable Vacía.";
}
else {
 $EquipoGanador="Variable No Vacía.";
}
```

Y este script me guarda en la tabla la palabra "Variable No Vacía". Pero nunca se imprime el valor original capturado del scrap.
Ver imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**ALGUNA IDEA?**

Comment: Ejecuta la sentencia `SHOW CREATE TABLE live_match_history;` y agrega el resultado a la pregunta. Verifica que estás revisando en el sitio correcto. Las imágenes de captura de la base de datos no coinciden con la imagen de lo que se imprime en pantalla, por ejemplo, en los datos impresos el equipo perdedor tiene `0` puntos y en la imagen aparece que tiene `2` puntos, por tanto, es una comparación no válida, podrías estar mirando en el sitio (fila) equivocado. Además en la imagen aparecen columnas que no son parte del `INSERT INTO`, deberías explicar por qué, pueden ser columnas obligatorias.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando parece que tienes todos los datos para generar la consulta SQL pero alguno no se inserta, posiblemente falte alguno de esos datos o haya algún otro problema con esa consulta SQL, haz un trazado antes de la inserción para comprobar que este correcta, por ejemplo:

```
//ESCRIBIMOS LOS DATOS EN TABLA MATCH HISTORY DE LA BASE DE DATOS
include('conexion.php');
$sql = "INSERT INTO live_match_history (NombreMatch, EstatusMatch, EquipoGanador, EquipoPerdedor, EquipoGanador_Puntos, EquipoPerdedor_Puntos, EnlaceMatch) VALUES ('$nombre_match','$status_match', '$EquipoGanador','$EquipoPerdedor','$EquipoGanador_Puntos', '$EquipoPerdedor_Puntos', '$url')";

/**
 * Aquí la traza de la consulta
 *
 */
echo 'INSERT -> ' . $sql . '<br>';

if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

Si el trazado parece correcto, pero aun así no inserta tus datos, puedes copiarlo y hacer el *INSERT* directamente en el *phpMyAdmin* que veo que estás usando, seguramente tienes los campos mal definidos y esta aplicación te indique el error. Y si aún no se insertan y *phpMyAdmin* no indica nada, comprueba la estructura de la tabla, el tipo de datos admisible y su longitud para esos campos.

Saludos.